# Firestore list of all collections

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have a list of json fieldnames in an array say..

```
eventVariables = ['customerName','date','amount'].
```

My JSON looks like..

```
info = {
'customerName':'Ashish Maity',
'date': '14-04-18',
'amount':'500'
}
```

Now I want send message to that customer, my message template is like:

```
smsBody = 'Dear customerName, we have received Rs.amount on date';
```

Now my requirement is I want to replace the variables(customerName,amount and date) in the smsBody with the value in the info JSON.

```
My code:
for(let i=0; i<eventVariables.length; i++){
 finalSmsBody = smsBody.replace(eventVariables[i],info[eventVariables[i]]);
};

My Output:
Dear customerName, we have received Rs.amount on 14-04-18
```

Only the last variable(date) gets replaced with the JSON value..I want that all the variables should be replaced with respective JSON value

Comment: The title mentions Firestore, and you've tagged with firestore, but the question doesn't say anything about Firestore. Is this question actually about Firestore and collections in Firestore?

Comment: Did my code worked for an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
for(let i=0; i<eventVariables.length; i++){
  smsBody= smsBody.replace(eventVariables[i],info[eventVariables[i]]);
};
```

Comment: @ashish-maity can up-vote this answer if above code solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
for (var key in info ){
   smsBody.replace(key,info[key])
}
```